# What do version numbers in CRS IRIs mean?

Tags: coordinate-system, ogc

By following the links on http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/ one can download identifiers/IRIs for various CRSes minted by the OGC.  For many CRSes, there seem to be multiple identifiers, differing in what looks like a version number.  E.g., for `EPSG:2000`:

```
http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/2000
http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/8.5/2000
http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/8.9.2/2000
http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/9.4.2/2000
http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/9.5/2000
http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/9.5.3/2000
```

Does anybody know what these version-like numbers refer to?  The OGC GeoSPARQL standard uses IRIs with `0` (i.e., the first IRI in the above list), but does not explain what the `0` stands for.

Comment: It is the version number of the EPSG database. The newest one is 9.5.4 http://www.epsg.org/

Comment: @user30184 make that the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @user30184 the numbers in the resolver URL refer to the version number of the CRS family (EPSG, OGC or IAU).  A special version indicator is written as "0". It indicates "no particular version" in general.

[Source](https://external.opengeospatial.org/twiki_public/CRSdefinitionResolver/WebHome):

> The resolver provides versioning of all definitions. To this end, CRS
>   URLs - following common OGC policy - contain a version indicator. For
>   example, in the following URL the "0" is such a version indicator:
>
> ```
> http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326
> ```
>
> Version identification adheres to the following rules:
>
> - a concrete version number has a syntax of n.n.n where n is a nonnegative integer number following OGC versioning semantics (first
>     digit change = possible backwards incompatibility; second digit change
>     = backwards-compatible change; third-digit change = bug fix). For EPSG definitions, OGC adopts the IOGP version number unaltered (note that
>     EPSG does not necessarily adhere to the OGC versioning semantics).
>
>   - Example: `http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/8.9.2/4326`
> - a special version indicator is written as "0". It indicates "no particular version" in general
>
>   - Example: `http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4326`